# Issue regarding pointer to array?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

I was trying to learn pointer to an array , but I'm not able to understand as to why *ptr and ptr print the same value

```
/*Here is the source code.*/

#include<stdio.h> 

int main() 
{ 
    int arr[] = { 3, 5, 6, 7, 9 }; 
    int *p = arr; 
    int (*ptr)[5] = &arr; 

    printf("p = %u, ptr = %u\n", p, ptr); 
    printf("*p = %d, *ptr = %d\n", *p, *ptr);  
    return 0; 
}
```

and here is a snapshot of the output I got:[image: How come ptr and *ptr return same values !!]

Comment: values *ptr and ptr are different, cause "%d" and "%u" used in printf

Comment: Do not post images of text.

Answer (score 1):

Change the way you print to this:

```
printf("p = %p, ptr = %p\n", (void*)p, (void*)ptr); 
printf("*p = %d, *ptr = %p\n", *p, (void*)*ptr);
```

since the format specifier `p` is used to print a pointer. Moreover, the pointer should be casted into a void pointer, when you intend to print it.

Possible output:

```
p = 0x7ffed5b62fd0, ptr = 0x7ffed5b62fd0
*p = 3, *ptr = 0x7ffed5b62fd0
```

where now you see that they are the same.